# Resource Query Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular.js app that has a productsCtrl.js that looks like:

```
app.controller('ProductsCtrl', ['$scope', 'Api', function($scope, Api) {
   $scope.products = Api.Product.query();

       //Delete Product
       $scope.deleteProduct = function(productId, idx) {
                Api.Product.remove({productId: productId});
                $scope.products.splice(idx, 1);
       };

 }]);
```

and the Api factory:

```
   app.factory('Api', ['$resource', function($resource) {
        return {
                 Product: $resource(
                            '/api/products/:productId',
                             {productId: '@productId'},
                             {'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: false }}
                 ),
                 Item:  $resource(
                             '/api/items/:itemId',
                             {itemId: '@itemId'}
                         )
                 };
              }
      ]);
```

If I change to `$scope.products = Api.Product.get();`, and try the splice method it says `TypeError: Object #<Resource> has no method 'splice'`.

If I keep the code the same (just like how the code is displayed above but change the *isArray* to **true**, then I get the error: `Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an array but got an object`

Comment: What is $scope.products?  Are you sure it is an array? Have you used debugging tools to teste?  What happens if you `console.log($scope.products)` it before trying to splice() it?

Comment: @the_ Invoking `query` on a `$resource` implicitly sets `isArray` to `true`. Also, `$scope.products` in the controller is automatically initialised to an empty object or array. For more details, see the documentation at http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource.

Comment: Just advice )) Try restangular.js https://github.com/mgonto/restangular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well one thing is clear, you get method on `Product` resource returns single item and not an array. So you should not name your controller property `products`. It should be

```
$scope.product = Api.Product.query();

//Delete Product
$scope.deleteProduct = function(productId, idx) {
            Api.Product.remove({productId: productId});
            $scope.product=null;
   };
```